# a counter-intuitive conclusion regarding the zero set of a truncated vanishing ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry

By the following simple construction i seem to be arriving at a conclusion that 
doesn't make sense to me.

**Question:** If the conclusion is correct why does it make sense?
If there is a flaw in my argument, where is it?

**Argument:** Let $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective variety with homogeneous 
vanishing ideal $I_Y = (I_s) =  I_s \oplus I_{s+1} \oplus \cdots$, $I_s \neq 0$.
In other words i am assuming that the generators of $I_Y$ are of degree $s$.
For some positive integer $\ell$ define the truncated ideal $I_Y(\ell) = I_{s+\ell} \oplus I_{s+\ell + 1} \oplus \cdots$.
Let $Y(\ell)$ be the zero set of $I_Y(\ell)$. Then $I_Y(\ell) \subset I_Y$ which implies that $Y \subset Y(\ell)$. On the other hand, the vanishing ideal of $Y(\ell)$ is
$I_{Y(\ell)} = \sqrt{I_Y(\ell)}$. Now for any $s \le \ell' < \ell$ take $m_{\ell'}$ to be the smallest positive integer such that $(s+\ell') m_{\ell'} \ge s+\ell$. 
Then $(I_{s+\ell'})^{m_{\ell'}} \subset I_{(s+\ell') m_{\ell'}} \subset I_{Y(\ell)}$. This shows that $I_Y \subset I_{Y(\ell)}$ and so $Y \supset Y(\ell)$, from which we conclude that $Y = Y(\ell)$. However this does not make sense to me intuitively since 
i would expect $Y(\ell)$ to be a proper superset of $Y$.

Comment: This all seems fine. Projective constructions don't usually care about what happens at the "finite" levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correspondence between ideals and subvarieties (or subschemes) is not as close in the projective setting as in the affine setting.

More precisely, two homogeneous ideals in $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ correspond to the same subscheme of $\mathbf P^n$ if and only if they have the same saturation with respect to the irrelevant ideal $\mathfrak m = \langle x_0,\ldots,x_n \rangle$.

In your case, since $I(l) \subset I$ the same inclusion holds for their saturations. In the other direction, if $r \in I$, then  $\mathfrak m^l r \subset I(l)$, showing that $r$ belongs to the saturation of $I(l)$ with respect to $\mathfrak m$. Saturation is idempotent, so this shows that the saturation of $I$ is contained in the saturation of $I(l)$.

Comment: Thanks. Just for reference, where exactly in Hartshorne is this stated?

Comment: I don't know where, if anywhere. But it's in Harris' _First course in algebraic geometry_, in Chapter 5. Also googling "saturation subscheme" or something similar will give lots of information.